# Can't Deserialize generic class with specific implicit method

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have an old type of data and what to convert it to another generic one using implicit method

it's works if you use types like long or string but with specific classes not...

```
void Main()
{
    var js = "{\"Content\":{\"B\": \"1\", \"C\": 1}}";
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(js);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public class A{
     public MLString<AB> Content {get; set;}
}

public class AB{
     public string B {get; set;}
     public int C {get; set;}
}

public class MLString<T>
    {
        public T DefaultValue;
        public Dictionary<string, T> Translates = new Dictionary<string, T>();

        public static implicit operator MLString<T>(T val)
        {
            return new MLString<T>() {DefaultValue = val};
        }

        public static implicit operator MLString<T>(Dictionary<string, T> val)
        {
            return new MLString<T>() {Translates = val};
        }   
    }
```

How can I desirialize it?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to what issue you're having? At a glance it looks like you're wanting a custom `JsonConverter`

Comment: @ColinM I have old fields in json in format like class AB but I want make it multilanguage and I tried use for it new generic class with dictionary "Translates"
And this generic class works for long or string.